# Wordpress CPT Url metabox collection

Tags: plugins, posts, metabox

How can I set for my Custom Post Type 'company' different url's if this company have multiple locations.

For example:
CPT: "company" with slug http://example.com/company
CPT Company Post:"Company ABC": http://example.com/company/company-abc

I have cmb2 (custom metabox 2) to add collection with some locations:
locations1 - USA, locations2 - UK, etc.

I want to display locations address if I type adres url:

USA meta locations if url http://example.com/company/parmeter/1
UK meta location if url http://example.com/company/parmeter/2

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a parameter with a new rewrite rule like that :

```
add_action("init", function () {

    add_rewrite_tag("%countryName%", "([^&]+)");

    add_rewrite_rule(
          "^company/([^/]*)/country/([^/]*)/?"
        , 'index.php?company=$matches[1]&countryName=$matches[2]'
        , "top"
    );


});
```

After adding this code, flush the rewrite rules of WordPress.

Then you can use URL like http://example.com/company/company-abc/country/UK
And then in the template, you retrieve the parameter with `get_query_var("countryName", NULL)`